# Is there a means of setting an alternative or a default for an undefined token?

Tags: 7, tokens

I am using the **nid** in combination with other fields to set the title of a node, but as the **nid** is only defined after the node creation, the initial title has a blank in the **nid**'s place.

I have to edit it again and clear the title before the title is set correctly. Is there some syntax or method which creates a default for a token if it's value is not yet defined?

Comment: Are you using your own implementation of title replacement or you're using another module like Automatic Entity label? Also, which Drupal version are you using?

Comment: What would the default be in this example?

Comment: @Clive The default in this instance would be 0, formatted as '0000'

Comment: @Ismail I am using Auto Entity Label

Comment: This is for Drupal 7 or Drupal 8?

Comment: This is for Drupal 7. Does Drupal 8 offer something extra in this regard?

Comment: Even if you set a default value (you could define a custom token in a module which returns a default if the node ID is not set yet) it won't get the correct value until the node is saved again. So you'll always see the default until you edit and save and so there's not much advantage over the present situation.